# How to append consecutively to a JSON file in Go?

Tags: json, go

I wonder how can I write *consecutively* to the same file in Go? Do I have to use `os.WriteAt()`?

The JSON is basically just an array filled with structs:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "2817293",
        "Data": "XXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2817438",
        "Data": "XXXXXXX"
    }
    ...
]
```

I want right data to it consecutively i.e. append to that JSON array more than once before closing the file.
The data I want to write to the file is a slice of said structs:

```
dataToWrite := []struct{
    Id   string
    Data string
}{}
```

What is the proper way to write consecutively to a JSON array in Go?

My current approach creates multiple slices in the JSON file and thus is not what I want. The write process (lying in a for loop) looks like this:

```
...
            // Read current state of file
            data := []byte{}
            f.Read(data)

            // Write current state to slice
            curr := []Result{}
            json.Unmarshal(data, &curr)

            // Append data to the created slice
            curr = append(curr, *initArr...)
            JSON, _ := JSONMarshal(curr)

            // Empty data container
            initArr = &[]Result{}

            // Write
            _, err := f.Write(JSON)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
...
```

Comment: You will need a different library. I, personally, had to write a json serializer at one point to work with longish json objects.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the opening `[` to the file.  Create an encoder on the file.  Loop over slices and the elements of each slice. Write a comma if it's not the first slice element. Encode each slice element with the encoder.   Write the closing `]`.

```
_, err := f.WriteString("[")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

e := json.NewEncoder(f)
first := true
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {

    // Create dummy slice data for this iteration.

    dataToWrite := []struct {
        Id   string
        Data string
    }{
        {fmt.Sprintf("id%d.1", i), fmt.Sprintf("data%d.1", i)},
        {fmt.Sprintf("id%d.2", i), fmt.Sprintf("data%d.2", i)},
    }

    // Encode each slice element to the file
    for _, v := range dataToWrite {

        // Write comma separator if not the first.
        if !first {
            _, err := f.WriteString(",\n")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
        first = false

        err := e.Encode(v)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
_, err = f.WriteString("]")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Z-T1nxRIaqL

---

If it's reasonable to hold all of the slice elements in memory, then simplify the code by encoding all of the data in a single batch:

```
type Item struct {
    Id   string
    Data string
}

// Collect all items to write in this slice.
var result []Item

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    // Generate slice for this iteration.
    dataToWrite := []Item{
        {fmt.Sprintf("id%d.1", i), fmt.Sprintf("data%d.1", i)},
        {fmt.Sprintf("id%d.2", i), fmt.Sprintf("data%d.2", i)},
    }

    // Append slice generated in this iteration to the result.
    result = append(result, dataToWrite...)
}

// Write the result to the file.
err := json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/01xmVZg7ePc

Comment: In the end I did follow your approach. Still not really satisfied tho. I would have liked to 'batch'-write to the file. But you would then need a way to concatenate the existing array (the file) and the array to append.

Comment: That was - in a slightly different way - what I did before. I kinda realised that what I want to achieve may not be doable. Basically write 500 elements to file and then grab another 500 and write them to file etc. Thats why in a way my initial problem was the grabbing the current state of the JSON array thats on file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the existing file you can just use `Encoder.Encode` on the whole slice as @redblue mentioned.

If you have an existing file you want to append to, the simplest way is to do what you've shown in your edit: `Unmarshal` or `Decoder.Decoder` the whole file into a slice of structs, append the new struct to the slice, and re-decode the whole lot using `Marshal` or `Encoder.Encode`.

If you have a large amount of data, you may want to consider using [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) to avoid the trailing `,` and `]` issue, and write one JSON object per line. Or you could use regular JSON, seek back from the end of the file so you're writing over the final `]`, then write a `,`, the new JSON-encoded struct, and finally a `]` to make the file a valid JSON array again.

So it depends on a bit on your use case and the data size which approach you take.

Comment: What I kinda have trouble with is the writing process. Right now the append operation is broken i.e. the JSON throws and error (End of file expected), because I have to arrays in one JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTICE**
This Answer is a `solution` or `workaround` if you care about the content of an existing file!
This means it allows you to append to an `existing` `json` file, created by your `API`.

Obviously this **only works** for arrays of **same structs**

actual working json format:

```json
[
object,
...
object,
]
```

When writing to a file, do NOT write `[` and `]`.
Just append to the file writing your serialized `json` object and append a `,`

actual file content:

```json
object,
...
object,
```

Finally when reading the file prepend `[` and append `]`

This way you can `write` to the file from multiple sources and still have valid `JSON`

Also load the file and have a valid input for your `json`-processor.

We write our logfiles like this and provide a vaild `json` via `REST` calls, which is then processed (for example by a `JavaScript` `Grid`)